# Spring Service - Should I pass an entity Id or the entity itself?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a `User` hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

If I want to create a `UserService` method that validates the credentials of a user, should the design of the `validate` method be like this:

`public Boolean validate(Long userId, String username, String password)`

or like this:

`public Boolean validate(User user, String username, String password)`

Which design would be better? Thank you for your time

Comment: I'd suggest to design your method this way `public Boolean validate(User user)`, so that you only have one parameter and someone who will read your method will know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DamCx thanks for your answer. My intent with the `validate` method is to check if the supplied `username` and `password` matches that user. I find that  on the first approach I could simply do sql like: `SELECT u.* FROM user u WHERE u.id = :userId AND u.username = :username AND u.password = :password` where on the 2nd approach, I would have to check them via Java

Answer (score 1):

Your design goal does not make sense to me.
The only time you should need a `username` and a `password` is during login.
At that time,
the `username` and `password` should uniquely identify a user.

I believe the method you want is this:

```
publid Optional<User> login(
    final String username,
    final String password);
```

Then either return an `Optional` that contains a `User` (as identified by the correct username and password combination) or return an `Optional` with `null` to indentify a bad combination of username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the User's instance with the given username, password and search in the database if the user is exits or not.

Pseudo code:

```
public booelan validate(User user) {
    userService.findUser(user) != null;
}
```

You should create the User's instance with the given username, password

`User user = new User(userName, password);\\I am assuming username should be unique`

Then use in your code:

```
if (isValidate(user)) {
    //doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a method in your UserRepository :

```
    User findByIdAndUsernameAndPassword(long id, String userName, String pass);
```

This will return a User if all of these fields match with a specific database entry.

**Passing entityId is better**, I hope this addresses what you were asking.